# React Modal Closing Early

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created a modal in React that is currently opening. However, no matter where I click, be it the close button, the modal body, or the background overlay, the modal closes.

I initially was not passing the Synthetic event into my handler. I have since passed in the object and tried adding `stopPropagation()`, `nativeEvent.stopPropagation()`, and `nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()` to no avail. The code is below, let me know what I messed up.

I am using styled-components for this project, so the wrapping JSX tags belong to styled components which I ommitted.

- Thanks.

Parent Component

```js
interface ParentProps {
    title: string;
    img: string;
    modalContent: JSX.Element;
}

function Parent(props: ParentProps) {

    const [modalize, setModalize] = useState(false);

    function toggleModal(event: SyntheticEvent) {
        setModalize(!modalize);
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.nativeEvent.stopPropagation();
    }

    return (
        <SkillBoxWrapper
            img={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/" + props.img}
            onClick={(e) => toggleModal(e)}
        >
            <BoxTitle className="title">{props.title}</BoxTitle>
            <Modal show={modalize} toggleModal={() => toggleModal}>{props.modalContent}</Modal>
        </SkillBoxWrapper>
    );
}
```

Modal Component

```js
interface ModalProps {
    children: JSX.Element;
    toggleModal: (e: SyntheticEvent) => void;
    show: boolean;
}

function Modal(props: ModalProps) {
    return props.show
        ? (
            <ModalBackground>
                <ModalDisplayArea>
                    <button onClick={(e) => props.toggleModal(e)}>X</button>
                    <div className="modal-content">{props.children}</div>
                </ModalDisplayArea>
            </ModalBackground >
        )
        : null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modal is within SkillBoxWrapper, which still listens to onClick when modal is shown and therefore toggles modal. You may only care for opening modal from SkillBoxWrapper, which solves the issue.

```
return (
        <SkillBoxWrapper
            img={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/" + props.img}
            onClick={(e) => { if(!modalize) toggleModal(e) } }
        >
            <BoxTitle className="title">{props.title}</BoxTitle>
            <Modal show={modalize} toggleModal={() => toggleModal()}>{props.modalContent}</Modal>
        </SkillBoxWrapper>
    );
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You have saved the remainder of my hair from being pulled

Comment: )). Glad to be of help